# Silently handle errors in powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am writing a troubleshooting script to determine which IP addresses in our Domain are accessible by WMI, and which are not. The script will read a list of input parameters (about 18,000 lines), and will output to a file the IP address and the username

```
IP address, Username
```

Problem is, when the WMI error is thrown, it writes to the file

```
IP address, Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. .....numerous lines of error
```

I would like to make it such that when a WMI error it thrown, it writes the following

```
IP address, "WMI ERROR"
```

And here is the modified code for reference

```
#script_modified.ps1

$abc = $args
$startInfo = $NULL
$process = $NULL
$standardOut = $NULL


<#Previously created password file in C:\Script\cred.txt, read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\Script\cred.txt#>
$password = get-content C:\Script\cred.txt | convertto-securestring

$a = Get-Content "C:\Script\test_input.txt"

foreach ($b in $a){

    $startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
    $startInfo.Arguments = "C:\script\script2.ps1 " + $b

    $startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $startInfo.CreateNoWindow = $false
    $startInfo.Username = "service.infosec"
    $startInfo.Domain = "Central"
    $startInfo.Password = $password 

    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $startInfo
    $process.Start() | Out-Null
    $standardOut = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $process.WaitForExit()

    # $standardOut should contain the results of "C:\script\script2.ps1"

   Add-Content C:\script\list_of_computers_in_DOMAIN.log $b","$standardOut
}
```

EDIT

@Hyper Anthony

I updated my code to the following

```
try{
    $process.StartInfo = $startInfo
}
catch{
    $message = "WMI ERROR"
}
finally{
    $process.WaitForExit()
    Add-Content C:\script\list_of_computers_in_DOMAIN.log $b","$message
}
```

And I get following errors:

```
Exception calling "WaitForExit" with "0" argument(s): "No process is associated with this object."
At C:\script\script_modified.ps1:36 char:29
+         $process.WaitForExit <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

How to fix?

EDIT:

Below is the updated code:

```
foreach ($b in $a){

    $startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"

    ...More Code...

    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $startInfo

    try{
        $process.Start() | Out-Null
        $standardOut = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    }
    catch{
        $standardOut = "WMI ERROR"
    }
    finally{
        $process.WaitForExit()
        Add-Content C:\script\list_of_computers_in_DOMAIN.log $b","$standardOut
    }

}
```

There are no longer any errors that get output to the console, BUT, the output file is not as I wish.

When there is an WMI error, I would like the following line to be written

> 'sender-ip=10.10.10.10', WMI Error

But instead, the following is written

> 'sender-ip=10.10.10.10',Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) ...many lines of error

or any other error may be printed instead of WMI Error.

Thanks once again!

Comment: You need to include `$process.Start()` in your try block -- that is the line that you want to catch an exception for. If you put too many lines in your try block then you may end up catching unintended exceptions, so put your `$process.StartInfo = $startInfo` line *before* the try/catch block. You're getting the exception in the finally block because, in this context, you've never started your process.  Try moving the answer as it is posted into your script, and let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: Try debugging your code to confirm that execution is actually being directed to the catch block on exceptions. The exceptions would not be caught if they are coming from another processes, and not the execution of `$process.Start()` itself.

Comment: Take a look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) documentation.  It looks like it returns a bool depending on if a new process is made. Perhaps you could handle it that way?

Comment: @Hyper Anthony: Now that you mentioned about Process.Start returning a Boolean, I am thinking may be source of this problem is the second script that is being called. I'll research more, and I'll post separate question.